# "A bunch of nincompoops!" Really ? In the 21st century?

Tags: word-usage

With the FIFA World Cup going on here, I recently heard a tourist use the word "nincompoop" in the sentence "A bunch of nincompoops!".  Then I realized I hadn't heard that word for a long, long time. To be more precise, since the 70's.   Is it still in use ?  Where ?

Comment: In polite society?

Comment: [On the rise since '95](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nincompoop&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnincompoop%3B%2Cc0)!

Comment: I fail to see the problem. It's a good word to use around children when you perhaps would like to use something less savory.  Besides that, I like the way it sounds.  It's an odd word and saying odd words can be fun.

Comment: Five times in 1 billion words... according to @BrianDonovan 's link.

Comment: @crownedjitter No problem about the word.  I just thought it wasn't used any longer.

Comment: Actually, that's five in 100 million--slightly less than half the current frequency of "ratiocination."

Comment: @Luis I agree that it probably is out of fashion.  I'm almost certain that it entered into my vocabulary from watching Looney Tunes cartoons when I was a kid.  Those cartoons date to the mid 20th century.

Comment: @BrianDonovan You're right. I counted one additional zero.

Comment: _Nincompoop_ is no longer viewed as obscene, if it ever was. Only obsolete. I've always favored it, though, because of its sound. /'nɪŋkəmpup/ is such a delightful word for an idiot.

Comment: It's only obsolete if nobody uses it-  I use it whenever it's called for. ;-)

Comment: Fashion be hanged. It's a fine word. If it fits, use it. That's how words come back into fashion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the decline since the 1940s, but not yet gone. Here is an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nincompoop&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnincompoop%3B%2Cc0) that llustrates.

Comment: I note that @Brian Donovan has the same link, offered long before mine.